# JavaFX - tree image

Tags: image, javafx, tree

Based on the Oracle sample, I've started to create my own treeview, which works well, but when I define an image to the root, the first line is underlined with red.

```
    private final Node rootIcon =  new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("root.png"))); 
    TreeItem<String> treeItemRoot1 = new TreeItem<String> ("Menu",rootIcon);
```

I if I take to another class which has "extends Application" it is fine. But I would like to use in a class which starts with:

```
      @Override
      public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
```

And this part  doesn't accept to write me"extrends Application" because it is going to be red either.

Answer (score 0):

I find out what caused the mistake and now I share with other beginners (just like  me).

If you want to use image to your treeview, you have to create the node Image in a normal class, and than you can call the picture under the override, for example:

```
     @Override

     public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

     TreeItem<String> treeItemRoot1 = new TreeItem<> ("Menu",rootIcon1);
     //......
```

So the point is that the line of defining the picture

```
   private final Node rootIcon1 =  new ImageView(new image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("root.png")));
```

MUST be out of the @override section.